# Orbeon Input field that is not present in output data?

Tags: variables, input, orbeon, transient

I am trying to build a form which provides user with two alternative form sections - let say "registration from" which contains only one date field for entering the beginning date and "registration from to" which contains one date field for beginning date and one date field for ending date.

My XSD dictates that only one of these sections can be presented in the output. For user convenience, my idea is to add an additional drop-down menu offering two options "from" and "from - to" and based on its value showing the corresponding section.

The problem is that I don't know how to add that dropdown menu without having its value in the output data?

Thanks Lukas

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved it by using instance in my model, so it looks lide this:

```html
<xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
    <xf:var name="elementName" value="//control-1"/>  
        <xf:instance id="DDinstance">
            <value/>
        </xf:instance>
        
        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <section-2>
                      ...     
                    </section-2>
                    <section-3>
                      ...      
                    </section-3>
                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>
```

I removed binding for my dropdown completely.
And in dropdown definitions I replaced reference to binding by reference to DDinstance:

```html
 <fr:dropdown-select1 xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl" id="control--control" ref="instance('DDinstance')">
                                ...
 </fr:dropdown-select1>
```

Comment: That will work, except that the resulting form definition might confuse Form Builder. Just be aware of that.

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate a little bit on what "might confuse" mean?
I've found out that having DDinstance as first causes problems with loading initial data. When I moved it after fr-form-instance it seems to work ok.

Comment: "Confuse" means that the modified form definition might make Form Builder and/or Form Runner crash. Currently, there is no documented set of safe changes you can make to a form definition, unfortunately.